# If $f$ is continuous and moderate decreasing, then Fourier transform of $f$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, fourier-analysis

> If $f$ is continuous and of moderate decrease, show that $\hat{f}$ is continuous.

***My attempt:***

$$ \hat{f}(\omega+h)-\hat{f}(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{-2\pi ix\omega}(e^{-2\pi ix h} - 1) dx $$

I am attempted to pass the limit. Namely,

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{-2\pi ix\omega}(e^{-2\pi ix h} - 1) dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{-2\pi ix\omega} \left(\lim_{h\to 0} (e^{-2\pi ixh} - 1)\right)dx = 0$$

But I suppose **since we have an improper integral here, we need to justify it.** For simplicity of notation, let $A = f(x)e^{-2\pi i x \omega}$. I start with

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\int_{-L}^L A(e^{-2\pi ixh}-1) dx = \int_{-L}^L A \lim_{h\to 0}(e^{-2\pi ixh}-1) dx=0$$

That means for any $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta$ such that

$$x\in (-\delta,\delta) \Longrightarrow \left|\int_{-L}^L A(e^{-2\pi ixh}-1) dx \right| < \epsilon$$

But this doesn't seem to get what I need. Any suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: don't know what is moderate decreasing, but I'd say that if $f$ is a bounded  and fast enough decreasing function, namely if  $|f| < C$ and for any fixed $\omega$ : $\int_L^\infty+\int_{-\infty}^L f(x) e^{- i \omega x} dx \to 0$ as $L \to \infty$ , then $\hat{f}(\omega)$ is continuous, because of what you wrote and of the epsilons

Comment: you should look at $f(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ since it is the prototype example of function whose $\hat{f}$ is not continuous

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by moderate decrease. I suspect you use an argument such as the following, assuming $f(t)t$ is absolutely integrable, for example:
$$
    \hat{f}(\omega+h)-\hat{f}(\omega)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)\{e^{-i\omega t}-e^{-i(\omega+h)t}\}dt \\
  =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)\int_{0}^{h}\frac{d}{du}e^{-i(\omega+u)t}du\,dt \\
  =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t) (-it)\int_{0}^{h}e^{-i(\omega+u)t}du\,dt \\
  = \int_{0}^{h}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)(-it)e^{-i(\omega+u) t}dt\,du
$$